# How To Pick Image From Gallery in Android App

Tags: java, android

i am trying to make an app in android that integrate Image Gallery with my app.
Following are the tasks my app dose :

1.First screen shows user with and Image view and a button to load Picture.
2.On click of “Load Picture” button, user will be redirected to Android’s Image Gallery where she can select one image.
3.Once the image is selected, the image will be loaded in Image view on main screen.

in addition to  these three above mentioned tasks i need my app to perform following tasks :

4.When the image is selected ,it is shown on main screen , when i go for more "load picture" option the previously selected image get disappeared ,but i need my app not to hide the previously selected image ,infact the all selected images it shows in a horizontally scrolling list on the main screen .and when i select any of them from a horizontal scrolling list they shown on the main screen .

for this my xml code is :

**main.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"></ImageView>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonLoadPicture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:text="Load Picture"
        android:layout_gravity="center"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

**java code :**

```
package com.ohile.imagegallerydemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class ImageGallery extends Activity {

    private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_gallery);

        Button buttonLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLoadPicture);
        buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent i = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Can you outline what your problem is?

Comment: the problem that i am facing is that when i load some more pictures from gallery the previously loaded picture get disappeared. how can i see the previously loaded picture on the main screen .

Comment: Do you want to keep displaying images which have been selected previously? - I think it needs imageviews more than one(like ListView).
Or do you want to keep file paths which have been selected previously? - I think it needs ArrayList(or any other Collection) to keep them...

Comment: yes i want this.i need code

Comment: no i want to keep displaying images selected previously

Comment: **[This Tutorial Can Help you](http://startandroiddevelopment.blogspot.in/2013/10/importing-image-from-gallery.html)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ListView (Horizontal Scroll) or GridView to Display your all selected Images. You can get idea from this [tutorial](http://ttlnews.blogspot.in/2011/04/horizontally-sliding-grid-of-images-in.html).

Comment: exactly i want the horizontal list view .can i get some code to achieve this